# Can't call methods on objects in pyObjC

Tags: python, delegates, quicktime, pyobjc, qtkit

When I call `setDelegate_` within my pyObjC code I get an `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'setDelegate_'`.

My Code looks like this:

```
def createMovie(self):
        attribs = NSMutableDictionary.dictionary()
        attribs['QTMovieFileNameAttribute'] = '<My Filename>'
        movie = QTMovie.alloc().initWithAttributes_error_(attribs, objc.nil)
        movie.setDelegate_(self)
```

**Edit**

I Found out that i can't use any instance methods with the movie object.

Comment: What does `QTMovie.alloc().initWithAttributes_error_(attribs, objc.nil)` return ? A tuple (`QTMovie`, `error`) ?

Comment: Actually it returns something like this:
`(<QTMovie: 0x7f840d875d30 time scale = 1000, duration = 8553387, rate = 0.000000, tracks = { 0x7f840c8c2240 0x7f840c81fa00 0x7f840ce0be50 0x7f840cf764b0 0x7f840b444590 0x7f840b42d6e0 0x7f840d40ed10 0x7f840cd31290 0x7f840c8d1b40 }>, None)`.

Comment: In Objective-C I think the code above code should run flawlessly.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're not working with Objective-C directly, but with an interface. Expect surprises...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, it looks like `QTMovie.alloc().initWithAttributes_error_` actually returns a two-element tuple, with the object you want as first element and some other object in the second element (possibly an error ?)

You should be able to access your object like that:

```
(movie, error) = QTMovie.alloc().initWithAttributes_error_(attribs, objc.nil)
```

Comment: Wow thanks! That was the solution. In Objective-C the error would be passed to the second argument but in pyObjC it is returned as a second element in a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

The selector "initWithAttributes:error:" has two arguments in Objective-C, the second of which is a pass-by-reference output parameter.   Python does not have pass-by-reference arguments, therefore PyObjC returns the value as a second return value, which is why the python wrapper for this selector returns a tuple. This is a general mechanism that's also used with other methods that have pass-by-reference arguments.

In Objective-C:

```
QTMovie* movie;
NSError* error = nil;

movie = [[QTMovie alloc] initWithAttributes: attribs error:&error]
if (movie == nil) {
   // do something with error 
}
```

In Python:

```
movie, error = QTMovie.alloc().initWithAttributes_error_(attribs, None)
if movie is None:
  # do something with error
```